# sql sum all columns separately

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table with about 50 columns. Most of them are  integer and double but some are string. **I want to sum all int and double columns separately in sql.**

I know I can do it like this:

> select sum(x), sum(y), sum(z) ..... from table_name

But i do not want to write sum(column_name) 50 times.

you know any solution?

Comment: *i do not want to write sum(column_name) 50 times.* But you must nevertheless.

Comment: You are completely right. Manually writing this query is tedious and error prone. The query you are looking for could be generated from the metadata tables.

Comment: You could consider using dynamic SQL to dynamically generate your select statement  based on INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables

Comment: @HansG - no need for dynamic SQL, unless you want to execute the query and not only generate it.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Please refrain from abusing your edit privileges like that in the future.

Comment: @Zoe, there was nothing wrong with the question. It seemed that for some reason I needed to edit it in order to reopen it.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz that's not the case, and it's _still_ not an appropriate use of edits. You have _more_ than enough rep to [cast reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as well, which also places the question into the reopen queue.

Comment: @Zoe who close and  who will reopen it. do i need to do anything? I am waiting a solve but question is not accepting answer. and there was no reason stated in my question to close it. Unbelievable.

Comment: @zoe, I haven't been active in SO for quite a while. I was looking for the reopen option but could not find it. My bad, I see it now

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prepared statement:

```
set @q = (SELECT concat('select ', group_concat(concat('sum(',COLUMN_NAME,')')), ' from table_name')
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
  AND DATA_TYPE in ('int', 'double'));
```

Then:

```
prepare stmnt from @q;
execute stmnt
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d680c70c8f792d85a1890e0cee890492)

Comment: it did not work for me.