# summing each row in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say for example I have:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| null | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

How do I sum each row in a single query if there even exist one. Or do I have to do it one by one. That would seem very inefficient especially if we had n columns. This should be the result:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |

Comment: my bad, I read your question too fast I guess, here is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834439/sql-sum-all-columns-separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want a simple query like this:

```
select sum(value1) as value1, sum(value2) as value2, sum(value3) as value3 from myTable
```

See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v5Fcij9ZkmAgjLqosHHkxg/0